# How do I set up the network drivers for Windows 7 on my iMac?

Tags: windows-7, drivers, boot-camp, network-adapter, imac

I installed Windows 7 32 bit on my 27" iMac OS X 10.6.6. When Windows loaded, I couldn't connect to the internet via wireless or ethernet. It appears the drivers are not correct?

I did the same installation a while ago on a 24" iMac (can't remember the OS X version) and when Windows loaded, the wireless worked.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Why would you spend all that money on a Mac then decide to run dodgy ole Windows??? That'd be the _first_ thing I'd say you did wrong :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: Sometimes you need to run proprietary software that only exists for one OS or the other. At least now you can install both on the same hardware.

Comment: Did you install this through boot camp? You need the boot camp drivers.

Comment: i used bootcamp to partition the drive and then went through the installation process of puting the windows disk in and letting it run its course.  how do i get the bootcamp drivers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just read further in the [Boot Camp installation guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en/boot_camp_install-setup.pdf), specifically Step 3: *Install the Boot Camp Drivers for Windows*.

See also: [Installing Boot Camp drivers](http://docs.info.apple.com/article.html?path=BootCamp/2.0/en/bc1143.html).

> You must install the Boot Camp drivers to use all the features of your
>   Mac with Windows. If it appears that the Boot Camp drivers weren't
>   successfully installed, try repairing them.
>
> To install or repair Boot Camp drivers:
>
> - Insert the Mac OS X Leopard disc or "Mac OS X Install Disc 1" into your computer.
> - Double-click the setup.exe file if the installer doesn't open automatically.
> - If you are repairing Boot Camp drivers that are already installed, click Repair.
> - Follow the onscreen instructions.

Comment: @user520300 - Yep. Drivers are right on the disk.

Answer (score -1):

iMac doesn't have a CD/DVD drive - download the Boot camp drivers to a USB thumb drive and install from there.